# Modal filter blur too slow [ionicFramework]

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I found really interesting bug. I have a semi- transparent modal and when I open it I want to blur the background. I'm doing it with the following code:

```
body.modal-open #mainPage{
   filter: blur(9px);
   -webkit-filter: blur(9px);
}
```

It works, but it's too slow. Usually the modal shows and the blur comes after 1-2 seconds. Why is this happening?

I even tried removing the animation of the modal with the following code, but I still get the same result:

```
.modal{
    transform:none !important;
    transition-duration: 0s !important;
}
```